# How can I override builtin login method in Loopback?

Tags: authentication, overriding, loopbackjs

I've created a new User model, based on builtin one. I'm trying this:

```
module.exports = function(TiUser) {
  TiUser.on('dataSourceAttached', function(obj) {
    var login = TiUser.login;
    TiUser.login = function(credentials, include, cb) {
      var result = login.apply(this, credentials);

      // Do my stuff
      cb(null, my_data);
    };
  });
};
```

But I can't get it working... What is wrong? or how could this be done right?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish specifically?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'd like to add role information along the user one. At this moment I'm doing 3 requests from the client side to get that information and I'd like to provide it with just one call. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to consider adding an `afterRemote()` hook to `login()`. Now you can achieve to add role( using `Role` model ) to user. For example:

```
TiUser.afterRemote('login', function(ctx, next) {

    //add role to the user.

    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this should be the way to go!

Answer (score 4):

At the end I've created a new method instead of overriding a current one:

```
module.exports = function(TiUser) {

  TiUser.auth = function(credentials, include, fn) {
    var self = this;

    self.login(credentials, include, function(err, token) {
      authInfo = {
        token: token
      };

      fn(err, authInfo);
    });
  };
  TiUser.remoteMethod(
    'auth',
    {
      description: 'Login method with Role data information embedded in return',
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'credentials', type: 'object', required: true, http: {source: 'body'}},
        {arg: 'include', type: ['string'], http: {source: 'query' },
          description: 'Related objects to include in the response. ' +
          'See the description of return value for more details.'}
      ],
      returns: {
        arg: 'accessToken', type: 'object', root: true,
        description: 'User Model'
      },
      http: {verb: 'post'}
    }
  );
};
```